# Using ExpressJS, how do I extract different data from a SQLite table using the URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, express

I want to access resources from a SQLite database table. I have one table for accounts, one for movies and one for reviews. The reviews-table is constructed like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    authorId INTEGER,
    movieId INTEGER,
    review TEXT,
    rating INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY('authorId') REFERENCES 'accounts'('id'),
    FOREIGN KEY('movieId') REFERENCES 'movies'('id')
  )
```

What I want to do is that I want to be able to get all reviews, made by one author. But I also want to be able to get all reviews, made for the same movie. Below is my code for getting all reviews made by the same user/author. The code looks the same when getting the reviews based on the movie, with a few changes.

Both of them does what I want them to do. But of course only the one written first in the file are running.

```
  const authorId = request.params.authorId;
  
  const query = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE authorId = ?";
  const values = [authorId];
  db.all(query, values, function (error, review) {
    if (error) {
      response.status(500).end();
    } else if (!review) {
      response.status(404).end();
    } else {
      response.status(200).json(review);
    }
  });
});
```

The url will look the same no matter which of them I want running; http://localhost:3000/reviews/3. How can I differentiate the url so that they know which one should run?

I have tried to experiment with query strings, but I'm not sure how that works, and after hours of searching for something that worked on my code, I gave up.

I have also been thinking about using something like

```
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  if (request.method == "GET" && request.uri == "/reviews/:authorId") {
    response.send("Hello World");
  } else {
    next;
  }
});
```

This didn't work, and it didn't work if I tried to remove ":authorId" from the url either. The page just keeps loading.

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The most dynamic would be a single route `/reviews` and use the query string with the params like `?author=123` or `?movie=123`, they can be combined like `?author=123&movie=123`. As you want to return JSON the code will be used via API, so the pretty path is usually not as important as when it is a web-url. To make the implementation effective, most people use a function where you can drop the query object in and get the where-clause, or use an ORM.

In express, when you have routers like '/reviews/:authorId' and then '/reviews/:movieId', then the second one will never be called, because the first one will always match. That is something to be careful about when organizing your express routes.